# How do I filter data using .date() keyword in the column name in django?

Tags: python, django, date, django-models, django-queryset

I am writing a web application using Django where I have to use `date()` in column name. The orignal field is `datetimefield` and i need filter using date only and ignore the time. Here is my code:

```
datas = Data.objects.all()
for data in datas:
    all = Data.objects.filter(datetime.date() = data.datetime.date())
```

But it gives out the following error:

```
all = Data.objects.filter(datetime.date() = consumption.datetime.date()) 

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Any idea how I use `datetime.date()` as a column name to use only date section of the `datetimefield` column?

**UPDATE**

Here is my model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: please, show your model, and add django version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `datetime` fields as `date` using the `__date` lookup:

```
datas = Data.objects.filter(datetime__date=datetime.date())
```

---

Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#date

Comment: You mean __date will act as .date() in on column name?

Comment: @Elisha512 Yes, that's what `__date` does.

Comment: @Elisha512 since your django version more Django 1.9.